# Get Slack channel ID with python slack sdk

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I'm writing a Slack bot that requires updating already posted messages, so I implemented this code using Slack python SDK:

```
def update_message(self, message_text, ts):
    response = self.client.chat_update(channel=self.channel, ts=ts, text=message_text)
    return response
```

The problem is that I only have the channel name, and the method `chat_update()` requires the channel ID.

How can I know the channel ID if I know the channel name?

Comment: How about `conversations.list` and go through the list to match the name? See https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.list

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a common problem with the Slack API. You might need to rely on [conversations.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.list)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a method like this to your class should help:

```py
def get_channel_id(self, channel_name):
    for result in self.client.conversations_list():
        for channel in result['channels']:
            if channel['name'] == channel_name:
                return channel['id']
    return None
```

Where `self.client` is a `slack_sdk.WebClient` instance.  Note that it can be quite slow so it's worth caching the answer if you'll be using it multiple times.